# fetch vs XMLHttpRequest: clarifications on the under the hood implementations

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, react-native

From React Native documentation:

> XMLHttpRequest API is implemented on-top of iOS networking apis.

In addition (from [Github issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/934))

> We polyfill the XMLHttpRequest API using native code when running in
>   the JavaScriptCore executor, because XHR is a browser API and as such,
>   simply doesn't exist in a pure-JS context.

But, what about `fetch`?

Since `fetch` is just a wrapper around XHR, I guess it will go through the native stack as well.

Are you able to confirm this?

Comment: I don't think *any* code has much choice beyond using native iOS networking APIs to perform network-related activity.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back with an answer to my question.

React Native network tasks (both `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`) use iOS networking API. This is also valid for Android stack.